# How to count in Grails/Hibernate: Message.countBy

Tags: sql, grails, groovy, hql

How do I count the number of messages where my body length is between 0 and 25 characters long?

```
Message.countBy('from Message m where m.body.length <= 25')
```

Unfortunately for me, `countBy` does not take a string parameter.

Comment: For now i'm just going to do the poor man's approach and load them into a map and do a for loop!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't know how to 'close' this message

Comment: Well, if the answer worked then you can click the check mark by the answer to accept it. If it didn't, then you can wait for a better answer or comment on why it didn't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the dynamic method reference, the best you can probably do is use `executeQuery` instead of `count*`:

```
Message.executeQuery('select count(m) from Message m where SIZE(m.body) < 25')
```

EDIT: Here are a couple of links that might help with writing/executing the query:

- [HQL Reference](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/queryhql.html)
- [Grails Domain Class Dynamic Method Reference](http://grails.org/DomainClass+Dynamic+Methods)

Comment: Thank you! You cannot do m.body.length i have discovered. You have to do SIZE(m.body)

But very close

Comment: I'll change it. I wasn't sure of the exact HQL, I had just copied what you were using, but with a different GORM method.